# Install sql server management studio API only

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have already installed sql server 2008 R2 , but now i need to install sql server management studio also ( i mean just that API ony ) is it possible to install only this instead of uninstall sql server 2008 R2 and Re-install sql server managemant studio 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just run setup again and choose "Add features to an existing installation." This image is for 2012 but same deal:

[image]

Then pick the instance you want to add features to (any 2008 R2 instance will do, if you have more than one instance installed). Again, this specific screen shot is not from the exact same version, but the process is the same:

[image]

And then on the feature selection screen, make sure the options outlined in red become checked (if they're not already):

[image]

Comment: there is no check box in feature selection

Comment: Show a screen shot, I don't know what you mean.